# Arduino built in example: "Dimmer" not responsive to serial data

Tags: arduino

Following this tutorial:
[Arduino LED Dimmer Example](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/communication/Dimmer)

I added the `Serial.println(brightness);` at the bottom to see what gets written to the brightness variable and only get back 48 no matter the value sent by serial to the arduino.

As you can see the value of brightness goes from 50 to 48 where it settles. The sent data is in pink and the black data is the response from the arduino.

What else could I try.
Thanks

Using the Hercules utility to establish a serial link to the arduino.
[Hercules Utility Showing communication with Arduino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEtoX.png)

The oscilloscope sees this:

[PWM signal from oscilloscope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rChNj.jpg)

```
const int ledPin = 9;      // the pin that the LED is attached to
void setup() {
  // initialize the serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize the ledPin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {
  byte brightness;
  // check if data has been sent from the computer:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    // read the most recent byte (which will be from 0 to 255):
    brightness = Serial.read();
    // set the brightness of the LED:
    analogWrite(ledPin, brightness);
    Serial.println(brightness);

 }
}
```

Comment: I guess it expects a byte sent for example by Processing, not a number as text sent from Serial Monitor.

Comment: @Juraj is assumingly right, perhaps reduce serial speed to lowest and film the oscilloscope (measuring the serial signal) with a mobile phone while sending a number (your oscilloscope does not seem to be a DSO). If step through the frames of the movie (e. g. with VLC) then you can see perhaps what is transferred over the serial interface. Of course the easiest way to use/purchase a quite cheap DSO with USB connection (e. g. PicoScope).

Answer (score 0):

your problem is obvious in the image you provided , for example in the image it shows
when send `100` , the arduino responded with `49` , `48` , `48` which is the ascii representation of the `100` , refer to [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/) where

> '1' is equivalent to 49
>
> '0' is equivalent to 48

which means that you send to the arduino the number **100** not as a number but as a string where your terminal sends `1` first in its ascii representation which is **49** then it sends `0` in its ascii representation which is **48** then it sends another `0` in its ascii representation which is **48**.

### **to solve this problem:**

in your pc side , try to change that in your terminal settings

**or**

in your arduino code , instead of `brightness = Serial.read();` write `brightness = Serial.parseInt();` , refer to [Serial.parseInt() docs](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/parseint/) where it says that :

> Looks for the next valid integer in the incoming serial. The function terminates if it times out

meaning that it will convert **"100"** (string) into **100** (number) in your arduino side .

also change `byte brightness;` into `int brightness;` as `Serial.parseInt()` **returns the next valid int**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you abdo salm, your suggestion educated me and resolved my problem at the same time. Answer updated for anyone who stumbles across the same rookie issue (see snippet below).

So in conclusion, the example code expected a number in the range of
00000000 to 11111111 (0 to 255 as a single binary byte)

I was instead sending multiple bytes that represented One, Zero and Zero on the ASCII table

```
11000100 (49)
11000000 (48)
11000000 (48)
```

erroneously thinking I was sending 100 which is `110010000` in binary.

I altered the code with `brightness = Serial.parseInt();` as  abdo salm suggested.

Here is the Hercules (or similar) friendly version of the Arduino Dimmer Example.

```
const int ledPin = 9;      // the pin that the LED is attached to
int brightness;

void setup() {
  // initialize the serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize the ledPin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  // check if data has been sent from the computer:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    // read the most recent byte (which will be from 0 to 255):
    brightness = Serial.parseInt();
    // set the brightness of the LED:
    analogWrite(ledPin, brightness);
    Serial.println(brightness);
  }
}
```

[image: Here is the new Hercules response.]

[image: And the scope changes as expected.]